# Having difficulty with finding a suitable $δ$ to prove $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}$ is continuous at $a$ $∈ (0,∞)$

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

So given any $ε > 0$, we want to find a $δ > 0$ such that if |$x - a$| $< δ$ then $|\frac{1}{x^3} - \frac{1}{a^3}| < ε$.

Firstly, we have

- $|\frac{1}{x^3} - \frac{1}{a^3}|$ = |$\frac{a^3-x^3}{x^3a^3}$| = |$\frac{x^3-a^3}{x^3a^3}$| = |$x-a$||$\frac{x^2 + xa + a^2}{x^3a^3}$| = |$x-a$|$\frac{x^2 + xa + a^2}{|x^3a^3|}$

Now I look to bound $\frac{x^2 + xa + a^2}{|x^3a^3|}$ to find a suitable $δ$.

Let $x$ $∈ (\frac{a}{2}, \frac{3a}{2})$ so that

- |$x-a| < \frac{a}{2}$  ⇒ $\frac{|a|}{2} < x < \frac{3|a|}{2}$

So we have (i) $x > \frac{|a|}{2}$ and (ii) $x < \frac{3|a|}{2}$ which will be used to find  $δ$.

Now,

- |$x-a$|$\frac{x^2 + xa + a^2}{|x^3a^3|}$ = |$x-a$|$\frac{x^2 + xa + a^2}{|x^3a^3|}$ < |$x-a$|$\frac{(\frac{3|a|}{2})^2 + \frac{3|a|}{2}a + a^2}{|(\frac{|a|}{2})^3a^3|}$ = |$x-a$|$\frac{\frac{9a^2}{4} + \frac{3a^2}{2} + a^2}{\frac{a^6}{8}}$ $^*$ = |$x-a$|$\frac{\frac{38a^2}{8}}{\frac{a^6}{8}}$ = |$x-a$|$\frac{38}{a^4}$

(Note at $^*$, since $a$ is always positive, I just dropped the modulus, is that ok?)

and now we rearrange |$x-a$|$\frac{38}{a^4}$ < $ε$ to get |$x-a$| < $\frac{a^4ε}{38}$.

So if I choose $δ$ = min${(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a^4ε}{38}})$ then for any $ε > 0$ if $|x-a| <δ$ we have

- $|\frac{1}{x^3} - \frac{1}{a^3}|$ < |$x-a$|$\frac{38}{a^4}$ < $ε$
  as required.

Is this a valid $δ$? Is my method good? It's a very long question so sorry for the long text but I tried using proper Latex everywhere.

Edit: Updated the error

Comment: $x^2+xa+a^2$ is not equal to $(x+a)^2$, but otherwise your approach is fine.

Comment: @Klaus Thanks, I edited in the change.

Comment: You corrected it the wrong way around. $x^3-a^3 = (x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)$, just the $(x+a)^2$ in between was wrong.

Comment: @Klaus Oh so my 1st answer was correct but I wrote the wrong expression in the middle

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @Klaus How do you check your own work to make sure you don't do silly mistakes like I just did? I've always had this problem